# Accessing Database Entities over a service

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework database first application running as a WCF service with the following method :

```
public USER_SESSION GetUserSessionDetails(string ID)
    {
        var ctx = new Entities();
        USER_SESSION user = new USER_SESSION();

        var userSessionDetails = ctx.USER_SESSION.Where(s => s.ID == ID)
                 .Select(s => new { s.USER_NAME, s.DATE_TIME, s.ID }).ToList()
                 .FirstOrDefault();

        user.USER_NAME = userSessionDetails.USER_NAME;
        user.ID = userSessionDetails.ID;
        user.DATE_TIME = userSessionDetails.DATE_TIME;

        if(userSessionDetails == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return user;
        }

    }
```

Now, no my client side, I want to access this method and pass the return value into an instance of the USER_SESSION database object like as follows :

```
USER_SESSION user = new USER_SESSION();
user = serviceClient.GetUserSessionDetails("2");
```

But my client has no knowledge of what the USER_SESSION object is - How can I access the database entities and objects over a service and use them in my client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When u add Service Reference or Service Reference to a Webservice, Proxy Classes of Webservice is Created on Client Application Hence u can access the Model in client also like:

```
SampleServiceReference.Sample s = new SampleServiceReference.Sample();
label1.Text=s.Name;
```

Where SampleServiceReference is Your Proxy Webservice Class.You Can View These Classes by selecting The Particular Service Reference and appropriate class

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I can access the methods of my service through my service reference but not the entity classes, can you tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are u asking about Entities Class...i.e in your 3rd line of Code?

Comment: Yep, I can't access the USER_SESSION objects but I can access the GetUserSessionDetails() method through the service reference

Comment: U can create Object of USER_SESSION by 
<YourReferenceName>.USER_SESSION obj; u can only Create the objects of model which your Webservice returns

Comment: apologies - i don't follow. Do I have to declare an instance of an object on the service in order to be able to use it in the client?

Comment: i don't understand,if your trying to access something like ctx.USER_SESSION on client side,then you can't,DbContext class is not there in proxy classes because you are only returning USER_SESSION type